# How to start git-bash with some argument on separate new window from Powershell

Tags: bash, git, powershell

I am trying to do the following steps from Powershell. Following is just a pseudo-code which explains my requirements.

```
# This is a powershell function  
function load(){  
    cd C:\my_path\scripts
    invoke-expression -Command C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe 
    # I want to go to this path into the git-bash.exe window
    cd C:\my_path\scripts 
    # I have bash script here. I want to excuete this script.   
    ./loadData.sh
}
```

how can I achieve this by Powershell? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `git-bash.exe --help` to see what parameters it has. after a short google search i assume you can run `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -ArgumentList '--cd="C:\my_path\scripts" --exec="loadData.sh"'` maybe even `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -ArgumentList '--exec="C:\my_path\scripts\loadData.sh"'` might work.

Comment: It just opens the git-bash in a new window and terminates without executing the loadData.sh script. It immediately closes the newly open window, so I can't tell what happened there. But loadData.sh takes more than 30 seconds and it gives lots of terminal output.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to execute the bash script `loadData.sh`, run :

```
cd C:\my_path\scripts
path/to/bash.exe loadData.sh
```

This will create a bash shell (in the current console, not in a separate one), run your script, and exit, returning to your powershell.

If the current working directory is not set as you expect within your bash shell, you can perhaps pass it as an argument to your script :

```
# not 100% tested, I don't have a Powershell at hand
path/to/bash.exe loadData.sh /c/my_path/scripts

# and in your loadData.sh, add an instruction :
cd "$1"
```